# Spawning Prefab spaws clone of Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a level editor and I need help spawning prefabs.

Below is the prefab that i'm using. Now, the code that I'm using makes it so when I click one of those orbs, a new Prefab is spawned in that diretion, and then disable the orb. And it kinda works:

[image]
[image]

Code for spawning:

```
void OnMouseDown()
 {
     Instantiate(prefab, transform.position + transform.forward, transform.rotation);
     gameObject.SetActive(false);
 }
```

Note: I did try to use PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab, but that didn't spawn anything:

```
void OnMouseDown()
 {
     GameObject currentTile = PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(prefab) as GameObject;
     currentTile.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position + gameObject.transform.forward;
     gameObject.SetActive(false);
 }
```

How do I pull this off?

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you are setting the orb inactive, you are doing it in the prefab and not in the instance. (The instance is the (clone) that appears in the scene). So that might be causing that when a new clone is created, the clone has the orb inactive already.

For that you should deactivate the orb through the instance instead of the orb of the prefab with something like:

```
Gameobject GO = Instantiate(prefab, transform.position + transform.forward, transform.rotation);
GO.orb.SetActive(false);
```

Making the corresponding reference to the orb public and added in the editor so that you can then hace access to it and you can deactivate it.
Hope that makes sense.